# Getting logging output and stdout in correct order in Jupyter Notebook

Tags: python, logging, jupyter-notebook

`logging` output is out of order in Jupyter Notebook, here is an example.

Plain ipython session:

```
In [1]: import logging                                                          

In [2]: for i in range(5): 
   ...:   print(i) 
   ...:   if i == 3: 
   ...:     logging.critical("critical") 
   ...:                                                                         
0
1
2
3
CRITICAL:root:critical
4

In [3]:
```

but in a Jupyter Notebook the output is out of order:

[image]

The `logging` output is printed before everything else. This makes debugging impossible as one loses any indication where the `logging` statement occured.

This happens with any logging level.

How can I get output in the correct order, as opposed to `logging` output getting its own special place?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can fix this by setting the `stream` to `sys.stdout`. This will remove any special treatment for logging messages in Jupyter Notebook I guess.

```
import logging
import sys
logging.basicConfig(stream=sys.stdout)
```

[image]